# Contagem acumulada de ocorrências de grupos em datas

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Estou com um conjunto de dados similar ao abaixo. Ele tem uma coluna com datas e outra com ocorrências de grupos nestas datas.

```
         data grupo
1  2019-01-01     a
2  2019-01-01     a
3  2019-01-01     a
4  2019-01-01     a
5  2019-01-02     b
6  2019-01-02     b
7  2019-01-02     a
8  2019-01-03     a
9  2019-01-03     a
10 2019-01-03     a
11 2019-01-04     a
12 2019-01-04     b
13 2019-01-04     b
14 2019-01-05     a
15 2019-01-05     a
16 2019-01-05     a
17 2019-01-05     b
18 2019-01-06     b
19 2019-01-06     a
20 2019-01-06     a
21 2019-01-07     b
22 2019-01-07     b
23 2019-01-07     a
24 2019-01-08     b
25 2019-01-08     a
26 2019-01-08     a
27 2019-01-09     a
28 2019-01-09     a
29 2019-01-09     b
30 2019-01-10     a
```

Eu desejo calcular a soma acumulada das ocorrências dos grupos em relação às datas presentes. Por exemplo, em 2019-01-01, o grupo `a` ocorreu 4 vezes. Em 2019-01-02, `a` ocorreu uma vez, o que dá uma ocorrência acumulada igual a 5. E assim por diante, para cada grupo e cada data.

As datas estão em sequência, mas algumas estão faltando. Os grupos não estão presentes em todas as datas. Isto posto, a resposta que procuro para o conjunto acima é a seguinte:

```
      data grupo acumulada
2019-01-01     a         4
2019-01-01     b         0
2019-01-02     a         5
2019-01-02     b         2
2019-01-03     a         8
2019-01-03     b         2
2019-01-04     a         9
2019-01-04     b         4
2019-01-05     a        12
2019-01-05     b         5
2019-01-06     a        14
2019-01-06     b         6
2019-01-07     a        15
2019-01-07     b         8
2019-01-08     a        17
2019-01-08     b         9
2019-01-09     a        19
2019-01-09     b        10
2019-01-10     a        20
2019-01-10     b        10
```

Abaixo estão os dados do exemplo para facilitar a vida de quem tentar resolver meu problema.

```
structure(list(data = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 
                                       17898, 17898, 17898, 17899, 17899, 17899, 17900, 17900, 17900, 
                                       17901, 17901, 17901, 17901, 17902, 17902, 17902, 17903, 17903, 
                                       17903, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17905, 17905, 17905, 17906), class = "Date"), 
                    grupo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), 
                                        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dentro do [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) existe a função `tidyr::complete()` para realizar o desejado.

Os passos para isso são:

1. Contar a ocorrência de cada grupo em cada data com `count()`.
2. Completar com 0 (zero) os casos em que não há observações
3. Fazer a soma acumulada desta contagem para cada grupo.

Isso pode ser feito com o código que segue:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  count(data, grupo) %>% 
  complete(data, grupo, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  mutate(n = cumsum(n))
```

Comment: Eu desconhecia a função `complete`. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Usando `data.table`:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

dados <- dados[, .(N = .N), by = c("data", "grupo")] %>% 
  dcast(data ~ grupo, value.var = "N", fill = 0) %>% 
  melt(., id.vars = "data", measure.vars = c("a", "b"), variable.name = "grupo", value.name = "N", ) %>% 
  setorderv(., c("data", "grupo")) %>% 
  .[, acumulada := cumsum(N), by = c("grupo")]
```

Resultado:

```
 > dados[]
          data grupo N acumulada
 1: 2019-01-01     a 4         4
 2: 2019-01-01     b 0         0
 3: 2019-01-02     a 1         5
 4: 2019-01-02     b 2         2
 5: 2019-01-03     a 3         8
 6: 2019-01-03     b 0         2
 7: 2019-01-04     a 1         9
 8: 2019-01-04     b 2         4
 9: 2019-01-05     a 3        12
10: 2019-01-05     b 1         5
11: 2019-01-06     a 2        14
12: 2019-01-06     b 1         6
13: 2019-01-07     a 1        15
14: 2019-01-07     b 2         8
15: 2019-01-08     a 2        17
16: 2019-01-08     b 1         9
17: 2019-01-09     a 2        19
18: 2019-01-09     b 1        10
19: 2019-01-10     a 1        20
20: 2019-01-10     b 0        10
```